# выдрать данные javascript из html

Tags: javascript, java

добрый день. есть страница с картой, на которой нанесены некие объекты. эти объекты жестко заданы в js коде страницы. надо их выдрать в java коде. пробовал натравить jsoup, но он не очень то хочет работать с кодом. вот пример

```html
marker = L.marker([56.71218916006565, 55.993525088012726], {icon: icons[15]});
                marker.on('mouseover', openPopup);
                marker.popupShown = false;
                marker.is_camera = true;
                if (marker.is_camera) {
                    marker.name = 'Город творчества';
                    marker.server = '11.34.178.158';
                    marker.number = '001-999-144';
                    marker.token = '80e0b21a1e3b4b5d832380b21b3254e4';
                } else {
                    marker.content = '';
                }
                marker.bindPopup('', {maxWidth: 175, closeButton: is_mobile(), closeOnClick: is_mobile()});
                if (!is_mobile()) {
                    marker.off('click');
                } else {
                    marker.on('click', openPopup);
                }
                marker.on('mouseout', function (event) {
                    var marker = event.target;
                    marker._hide_timer = setTimeout(function () {
                        hidePopup(marker);
                    }, 1000);
                });
                marker.on('popupopen', function () {
                    if (this.is_camera) {
                        window.cache.camera = {
                            name: this.name,
                            server: this.server,
                            number: this.number,
                            token: this.token
                        };
                        this.getPopup().setContent('<a class="cursor" id="PopupOnMarker"><span class="ClickToView">Нажмите для просмотра</span><img style="border:0;width:170px;height:150px;" width="170" height="150" src="http://' + this.server + '/' + this.number + '/preview.jpg?token=80e0b21a1e3b4b5d832380b21b3254e4"></a>');
                    } else {
                        this.getPopup().setContent(this.content);
                    }
                });
                marker.on('popupclose', function () {
                    this.getPopup().setContent('');
                });
                marker.addTo(layouts['gorod-tvorchestva']);
            
                marker = L.marker([53.729585327853944, 55.948357545362974], {icon: icons[15]});
                marker.on('mouseover', openPopup);
                marker.popupShown = false;
                marker.is_camera = true;
                if (marker.is_camera) {
                    marker.name = 'Город творчества';
                    marker.server = '11.30.138.138';
                    marker.number = '001-999-150';
                    marker.token = 'bd22d27e201144dc8c28043b865c5736';
                } else {
                    marker.content = '';
                }
                marker.bindPopup('', {maxWidth: 175, closeButton: is_mobile(), closeOnClick: is_mobile()});
                if (!is_mobile()) {
                    marker.off('click');
                } else {
                    marker.on('click', openPopup);
                }
                marker.on('mouseout', function (event) {
                    var marker = event.target;
                    marker._hide_timer = setTimeout(function () {
                        hidePopup(marker);
                    }, 1000);
                });
                marker.on('popupopen', function () {
                    if (this.is_camera) {
                        window.cache.camera = {
                            name: this.name,
                            server: this.server,
                            number: this.number,
                            token: this.token
                        };
                        this.getPopup().setContent('<a class="cursor" id="PopupOnMarker"><span class="ClickToView">Нажмите для просмотра</span><img style="border:0;width:170px;height:150px;" width="170" height="150" src="http://' + this.server + '/' + this.number + '/preview.jpg?token=bd22d27e201144dc8c28043b865c5736"></a>');
                    } else {
                        this.getPopup().setContent(this.content);
                    }
                });
                marker.on('popupclose', function () {
                    this.getPopup().setContent('');
                });
                marker.addTo(layouts['gorod-tvorchestva']);
```

необходимо выдрать  name, server, number и token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
Document doc = ...
Element script = doc.select("script").first(); // Get the script part


Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?is)key=\"(.+?)\""); // Regex for the value of the key
Matcher m = p.matcher(script.html()); // you have to use html here and NOT text! Text will drop the 'key' part


while( m.find() )
{
    System.out.println(m.group()); // the whole key ('key = value')
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // value only
}
```

Comment: что-то я с регуляркой не понял.. что туда подставить надо? с таким текстом m.find() у меня false сразу же

Comment: в регулярке вместо `key=` надо `name=`, `server=` и т.д.